# Applying the Exchange Lemma to Linearly Independent Sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been using the following version of the exchange lemma: Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$. Let $\{u_{1},\dots, u_{n}\}\subseteq V$ and $\{w_{1},\dots, w_{m}\}\subseteq V$ for some $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $u_{1},\dots, u_{n}$ be linearly independent and $u_{1},\dots, u_{n}\subseteq \mathrm{span} (w_{1},\dots, w_{m})$. Then we have $n\leq m$ and, after rearranging the $w_{i}$ if necessary, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{span}(w_{1},\dots,w_{m})=\mathrm{span}(u_{1},\dots, u_{n},w_{n+1},\dots, w_{m}).
\end{align*}

I've been trying to show for a while now that if the vectors $w_{1},\dots, w_{m}$ are linearly independent, then the vectors $u_{1},\dots, u_{n},w_{n+1},\dots, w_{m}$ have to be linearly indepenent as well. However, so far all my attempts have been fruitless. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to reformulate the lemma is that in a vector space $W$ spanned by $m$ vectors $w_1,...,w_m$ it is impossible to have more than $m$ linear independent vectors. (indeed the lemma states that $u_1,...,u_n$ linear independent in $W \implies n\leq m$)

In the case where $w_1,...,w_m$ is itself linear independent then you have the following result

> If $v_1,...,v_m$ is such that $span(v_1,...,v_m) = W$ then $v_1,...,v_m$ is linearly independent.

This is not too difficult to prove by contradiction:

> If $v_1,...,v_m$ is not linear independent then it has a linear independent subset $v_1,..., v_k$ with $k < m$ which is such that
> $$W = span(v_1,...,v_k)$$
> Since $w_1,...,w_m$ linear independent in $W$ it follows by the exchange lemma that $m \leq k$ which is impossible since we know $k <m$.

---

This is exactly the context of your problem with $v_1,...,v_m =u_1,...,u_n,w_{n+1},...,w_m$

Comment: That works, thanks for your help :)